# Why do we define the complex exponential as we do?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

Why do we define the complex exponential as we do? Defining $e^{z}$ as $e^{x}e^{iy}$ certainly seems to make sense, but I'm not sure the formal reason as to why it's defined like this. Was it from looking at Taylor Series, or was it just because we want the nice multiplicative structure? We can show that the real exponential function splits over addition, but the complex one has an addition that is different, so is it simply defined as I stated above, or is there an obvious thing I'm missing?

Comment: Who defines it that way?

Comment: How is this different from the real case? $e^{x+y}=e^x e^y$

Comment: You could define it so that $\exp:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C^\times$ is a group homomorphism, or you could define it by allowing complex values in the real Taylor series, or as the unique holomorphic function satisfying $f'(z)=f(z)$ subject to $f(z)=1$. Any way works, and they all seem pretty natural. Why do you believe something's missing from this picture?

Comment: In my case, we first showed that the exponential series absolutely converges for any $z$ and then we defined the exponential of $z$ as $\sum z^n / n! $.

Comment: There exist only 1 entire analytic function that match the exponential on the real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:  we don't always.

Many places will define the complex exponential by the power series:

$$\exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^n\over n!}$$

and justify that by analyticity, this always matches the value on the real axis.

From here one can verify that it satisfies the functional equation

$$\exp(z+w)=\exp z\exp w$$

directly by treating $w$ as fixed, but arbitrary and performing the analysis on the variable $z$.

Certainly the definition you mention makes some sense, as wanting the complex exponential to behave the same way as the real one by demanding the functional equation hold can give rise to the equations

$${\partial\over \partial x}(e^xe^{iy})=e^xe^{iy},\; {\partial\over\partial y}e^xe^{iy}=ie^xe^{iy}$$

From there we use that

$${d\over dz}={1\over 2}\left({\partial\over\partial x}-i{\partial\over\partial y}\right)$$

With the given definition, we get:

$${d\over dz}e^z={1\over 2}\left(e^xe^{iy}-i\left(ie^xe^{iy}\right)\right)=e^xe^{iy}=e^z$$

so that the complex exponential satisfies the appropriate differential equation, one of it's best properties from real variables, so it supports the choice made there.

Comment: How would you show the sum formula from the Taylor Series?

Comment: @Anthony Treat $w$ as fixed, then take the derivative with respect to $z$, you get term-by-term differentiation justified by uniform convergence on compact sets. Since the only solutions to $y'=y$ are of the form $Ae^z$ we see that, since our constant is a function of $w$ we have

$$\exp(z+w)=A(w)\exp(z)$$

Then take the derivative of the original power series with respect to $w$ and we get that this is equal to $B(z)e^w$, from which we get what we want.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were implying we could do it just by expanding/collapsing sums. That makes sense then.

What justification do we have for treating $i$ as a constant. Is that just something in our definition of a complex derivative?

Comment: The chain rule is proved for one-dimensional things, not real things, so the $iy$ direction still gives ${\partial\over\partial y}e^{iy}=e^{iy}{\partial\over\partial y}(iy)$, the latter of which can be verified to be $i$ by the definition of the derivative.

The main point being that derivatives are--at their heart--limits, which involve arithmetic in a field, but if you look at the limit laws, they don't depend on the constants involved being real numbers, only that there is a continuous path to the point in question for which a line--i.e. the imaginary axis--counts.